Import "pyodbc" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource
In our python file inside VSCode editor, the import pyodbc declaration gives the following error:

Import "pyodbc" could not be resolved from sourcePylancereportMissingModuleSource

However when I try to install pyobdc, I get the following message:
PS C:\PyCopilotProject\my-python-project> pip install pyodbc
Requirement already satisfied: pyodbc in c:\users\myusename\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (4.0.32)

And the following code verifies that the package pyodbc (4.0.32) is indeed installed.
PS C:\PyCopilotProject\my-python-project> pip list

Question: What could be a cause of the error and how we can resolve it?

It depends on what interpreter you're running import pyodbc. 1. Are you using a virtual environment? If no, it is recommended to use virtual environments to manage your projects. So create a virtual environment and install pyodbc therein. 2. If working with global installations, it appears that pyodbc is currently installed in your python 3.10 interpreter. Are you also using Python 3.10 to run your code? Do you have multiple python versions?, you might be using a different version than the one that has the module installed. 3. Your vscode might have another python version added to its path.

@16171413 Your comment helped me resolve the issue. I'm using virtual environment. It seems the issue was that environment got deactivated (for some reason) before I ran the pip install pyodbc command. After I ran PS C:\PyCopilotProject\my-python-project> venv\Scripts\activate to activate the environment, and then ran pip install pyodbc, issue got resolved. If you like, you can convert your comment into a response with some details - and I will mark it as an answer.

Glad it worked... I've moved to answer

It depends on what interpreter you're running import pyodbc.

Are you using a virtual environment? If no, it is recommended to use virtual environments to manage your projects. So on Windows, create a virtual environment using:

python -m venv path\to\venv

Ensure your virtual environment is activated:
path\to\venv\Scripts\activate

and install pyodbc in the active virtual environment
pip install pyodbc


If working with global installations, it appears that pyodbc is currently installed in your python 3.10 interpreter. Are you also using Python 3.10 to run your code? Do you have multiple python versions?, you might be using a different version than the one that has the package installed.
Ensure you are using the right interpreter on vscode especially if you have multiple python versions.

